# Print array value PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a little problem when trying to print certain values from my database. OK so I have a table in my database called `site_details` where I save the site name, phone and email. I have a query that returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => My Store
            [0] => My Store
            [column_key] => site_name
            [1] => site_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => (123) 456 7890
            [0] => (123) 456 7890
            [column_key] => site_phone
            [1] => site_phone
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => email@yahoo.com
            [0] => email@yahoo.com
            [column_key] => site_email
            [1] => site_email
        )

)
```

I would like to print out the site details using the following code:

```
//Print out site name
//$site_details is the array being returned from the database
<?php echo $site_details['site_name']; ?>
```

This returns an

> Undefined index: site_name error

. Anyone know how I could go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here's the code i use to return the site details:

Funtions.php

```
public function getSiteDetails(){
    global $pdo;

    $getDetails = $pdo->prepare("
        SELECT *
        FROM site_details
    ");
    $getDetails->execute();

    return $getDetails->fetchAll();
}
```

This is where I call the function:

index.php

```
require 'res/php/Functions.php';
$obj = new Functions();

//Get site details
$site_details = $obj->getSiteDetails();
```

Database image:
[image: Database Image]

Comment: The array you showed us doesn't have a key `'site_name'`, so the code at the bottom will not echo anything useful.   Tell us what you want the output to look like, based on the site detail values above

Comment: you can print out the indexes present n your array like `<?php echo $site_details[0]['text']; ?>` etc

Comment: Please show your code where you've written your query. I think you might have used fetch_array here. fetch_assoc would be the best option.

Comment: Just updated the question guys.

Comment: @ExoSkeleton321 your update didn't address my comment (first one in the chain). Still don't know what your desired output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given  array the `printing` mechanism is as follows:-

```
<?php

foreach($site_details as $site_detail){

   echo $site_detail['column_key'].' is:- '.$site_detail['text'];
}

?>
```

Note:- `fetch_assoc` will be better objective.

Also every column value comes separately which shows you did something extra in your code, which is actually not needed

***for each value to print:-***

```
<?php echo $site_details[0]['text']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I print each value outside of a loop. I don't wnat to print them all at once.

Comment: `<?php echo $site_details[0]['text']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$getDetails>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` that gives an array like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => My Store
            [column_key] => site_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => (123) 456 7890
            [column_key] => site_phone
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => email@y
            [column_key] => site_email
        )

)
```

Then use,

```
echo $site_details['column_key'];
```